# Heroku Redis silently failing, but ActiveJob "Enqueued"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, heroku-redis

I have two apps setup identically on Heroku with Redis and Resque, except on my production environment I have a paid database provisioned, and on my staging environment I have all the free defaults. Staging works exactly as expected, but production isn't processing any redis jobs. The only indication in the logs that anything is happening when a job is triggered is this line:

```
2022-04-14T15:20:54.033357+00:00 app[resque.1]: I, [2022-04-14T15:20:54.033186 #8]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CacheUserMapJob] [4ea5f7fb-1f06-4565-982a-9d9f80844ab6] Performing CacheUserMapJob (Job ID: 4ea5f7fb-1f06-4565-982a-9d9f80844ab6) from Resque(logbook_viz_production_default) enqueued at 2022-04-14T15:20:50Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007efe477ce740 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://logbook-viz/User/64>>
```

The only other call to resque or redis in the logs is:

```
2022-04-14T15:18:16.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-animated-90457 sample#active-connections=4 sample#load-avg-1m=0.305 sample#load-avg-5m=0.62 sample#load-avg-15m=0.975 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.18627 sample#memory-total=15617708kB sample#memory-free=8320632kB sample#memory-cached=4448168kB sample#memory-redis=425496bytes sample#hit-rate=0.52445 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

I've obviously got a setting or something wrong. I'm assuming there is something I need to do to connect redis to the upgraded database, but I can't find it in any documentation anywhere. Any ideas from the above logs?

Comment: You may find something useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612686/background-jobs-with-resque-on-heroku

I'd suspect it has to do with your procfile

Comment: Make sure you have TLS setup when connecting to the Production database instance: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#provisioning-the-add-on.